# How to use setIn with immutable.js List

Tags: immutable.js

Ok I've got a list of objects, pretty standard.

`const list = Immutable.List([{type:'thang',data:{id:'pants'}}]);`

Now I want to change pants to shorts... so I'm thinking

`list.setIn([0,'data','id'],'shorts');`

Alas

`Error: invalid keyPath`

How is this done?

I can't even get this far despite messing around with this for a while :/ Once I know how to do this I'd like to know how to add a new element at a position

`list.setIn([0,'data','length'],'short');`

To add a new length attribute to the data object at position 0 in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad. I was going wrong with the creation of the Immutable structure. If I change

`const list = Immutable.List([{type:'thang',data:{id:'pants'}}]);`

To

`const list = Immutable.fromJS([{type:'thang',data:{id:'pants'}}]);`

Then I can

`list.setIn([0,'data','id'],'shorts');`

Comment: A common immutable gotcha :). List/Map etc functions don't do deep conversions. Use `fromJS` for nested conversions.

Answer (score 3):

Our nested structured data:

```
const state = {
  Persons: [
    {
      fname: 'J.R.R',
      lname: 'Tolkin',
    },
    {
      fname: 'jack',
      lname: 'London',
    }
  ]
};
```

**Requiring Immutable**

```
const { fromJS } = require('immutable')
```

**Turning simple object to Map**

```
const stateMapped = fromJS(state);
```

**Getting Data from nested structure**

```
console.log(stateMapped.getIn(['Persons', 0, 'fname']))//output: J.R.R
```

**setting data in nested structure**

```
var objClone = stateMapped.setIn(['Persons', '0', 'fname'], 'John Ronald Reuel');
console.log('' + objClone.getIn(['Persons', 0, 'fname'])); //output: John Ronald Reuel
```